# Multiple nested forms in rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, nested-forms

I'm looking into nested attributes and I have a few questions about relationships between models.

Say I have a **Show** that has_many **Seasons**. Both **Show** and **Season** can have many **Actors** and **Staff**. See table example:

[image]

When a **Show** is created, **Season** accepts the **Show** association and both **Actors** and **Staff** accept both the **Show** and **Season** attributes. Would this be a triple nested form?

So my models would look like this?

```
class Show < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :seasons, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :actors, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :staff, dependent: :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :seasons, allow_destroy: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :actors, allow_destroy: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :staff, allow_destroy: true
end

class Season < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :show
  has_many :actors, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :staffs, dependent: :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :actors, allow_destroy: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :staff, allow_destroy: true
end

class Actor < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :show
  belongs_to :season
end

class Staff < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :show
  belongs_to :season
end
```

And my Show Controller would look like:

```
class ShowsController < ApplicationController
  def create
   @show.seasons.build
   @show.seasons.build.actors.build
   @show.seasons.build.staffs.build
  end
end
```

Comment: If I understand the problem correctly, when Show is created you also want to create a Season (one) for this Show, and Actors (many) and Staff (many), correct?

Comment: Yes, thats correct.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Your data schema is incorrect then. In code model `Actor` `has many shows` and `has many seasons`. The same for `Staff`. But above the schema you wrote: `Both Show and Season can have many Actors and Staff`

Comment: Ok. So I have updated my models above. Is this correct? And to build the Actor and Staff nested attributes do I do what's in the Show Controller?

Comment: Oh, I didn't see your comment and wrote an answer. Yes, now it is correct

Comment: However controller's method won't work this way

Comment: also please see offtopic from the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct schema is:

```
class Show < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :seasons, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :actors, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :staff, dependent: :destroy

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :seasons, allow_destroy: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :actors, allow_destroy: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :staff, allow_destroy: true
end

class Season < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :show
end

class Actor < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :show
  belongs_to :season
end

class Staff < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :show
  belongs_to :season
end
```

The rule is simple - if table `objects` has a foreign key `subject_id`, which links it to table `subjects`, then model `Object` may contain `belongs_to :subject` association.

There is a nice [explanation](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#module-ActiveRecord::Associations::ClassMethods-label-Is+it+a+-23belongs_to+or+-23has_one+association-3F) about which relationship to use in your model depending on foreign_key placement.

**Off-topic:**

I don't know the specifics of your project, but it looks a bit offensive. You create new actors and staff each time a new show is created like they are expendable. I do not want to seem cynical, but the actors and the staff can be reused. If so, it could be reasonable to create [has_and_belongs_to_many](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_and_belongs_to_many) relationships.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Appreciate it.

Comment: I have another question about these nested forms, similar to this, but with a a trickier outcome if you have the time?

Comment: Yes, sure, what's the question?

Comment: Should I open a new question?

Comment: No, you can write here. It's more convenient to open a chat, however I cannot find how to do it :(

Comment: I have just invited you to a room.